# Diffeomorphism which has a zero

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:B(x_0,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a diffeomorphism between $B(x_0,r)$ and its image. 
If $|f'(x)^{-1}| \leq M$ for all $x \in B(x_0,r)$ and $|f(x_0)|<r/M$, show that $f$ has a zero.

It seems to me that we have to use the Mean Value Inequality for the inverse map, but I didn't got anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this.  Suppose $0$ is not in the image.  Look at the straight line segment joining $y_0 = f(x_0)$ to $0$.  Let $$t_1 = \inf\{t\in[0,1]:(1-t) y_0 \notin f(B(x_0,r))\},$$
that is, $y_1 = (1-t_1)y_0$ is the first point along the straight line seqment that lies on the boundary of the image of $f$.  Consider the straight line segment $s$ that joins $y_0$ to $y_1$ that is closed on the left and open on the right, that is $s = \{(1-t)y_0 : 0 \in [0,t_1)\}$.  Look at $$f^{-1}:s  \to \mathbb R^n.$$  The derivative of this map is bounded.  This means that $x_1 = \lim_{t\to t_1} f^{-1}((1-t)f(x_0))$ exists.  Furthermore, $x_1$ is on the boundary of $B(x_0,r)$.

Since the derivative of this map is bounded by $M$, the distance between $x_0$ and $x_1$ is $M$ times less than or equal to the distance between $y_0$ and $y_1$, and hence this distance is less than $r$, which is a contradiction.

It's easier to follow this if you draw pictures.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you about this... would you elaborate more on why the limit which defines $x_1$ exists?

Comment: @user2345678 I think I was thinking to use the chain rule to show that it is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't see your point. I was thinking about using the fact that $f^{-1}$ is locally lipschitz to ensure the limit exists, but I can only ensure that within open balls (convex sets). I'm not sure how $f^{-1}$ behaves near the point at the boundary

Comment: I must admit to not really understanding your question.  We are told that the derivative of $f^{-1}$ is bounded on the image of $B(x_0,r)$.  And the set $s$ is convex set that lies within this image.  So $f^{-1}$ is globally Lipschitz on $s$.