# Image of a ball by a diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, diffeomorphism

Let $f:B_r(x_0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism with $\Vert f'(x)^{-1}\Vert \le M$ for all $x\in B_r (x_0)$ and $\vert f(x_0)\vert <\frac{r}{M}$.

I'm wondering if I can say that the set $f(B_r(x_0))$ is convex. I was thinking it could be true, but I didn't find this result, so I was in doubt, but I can't demonstrate the result or find a counterexample.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The ideas I had, guarantee this result only locally, for example, being locally lipschitz and locally uniformly continuous, but I didn't think of a way to guarantee this globally.

Comment: You have a typo in the last hypothesis. Why is the location of $f(x_0)$ even relevant? What is this actually supposed to say? How are you approaching the problem? What is a reasonable way to phrase the convexity question? (Oh, and you mean *ball*, not *sphere*, in the title.)

Comment: @TedShifrin This question was part of another exercise, which I solved in one way, but I would be able to solve it in another way if I could guarantee that this set is convex..... I don't know if I made it clear, but I couldn't think of a reasonable way to answer my question, my ideas are just intuitive ....

Comment: Diffeomorphisms certainly can turn balls into non-convex sets. I see no reason this should be true. I'm guessing you're doing some sort of contraction mapping or inverse function theorem exercise.

Comment: @TedShifrin The exercice is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367020/diffeomorphism-which-has-a-zero), I found this solution interesting, but I didn't see that that limit exists without guaranteeing the convexity of space, nor did I think of a way to guarantee convexity around a point on the boundary.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is simply false (in every dimension)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Show a counterexample.

Comment: For $x_0=0$, take **any** diffeomorphism from the closed ball $\bar{B}(x_0,r)$ to **any** closed nonconvex region sending $x_0=0$ to $0$.